# Passing one of the Header value from Rest API request to iterate over getting the response while copying data from API to azure synapse

Tags: azure, rest, azure-synapse

I am working to pull some objects from an Rest API endpoint where the response is restricted to send only 500 items in one call.

I am doing it in azure synapse and unable to get the specific header value which need to be passed into  copy activity to continue the loop until all the data is retrieved.

Can someone help in this ?

Comment: What API?  What have you tried?

Comment: its showpad rest api endpoint that i am working on , i need to pull the events which is basically fact data ..i am trying to get the access token and passing it into a copy activity as below but as per the limit they have its just giving me 500 records in the response data.

Comment: The response will come with a header called X-Showpad-Scroll-Id that contains a token. If you make the same request again but set this header on your request, you will get the second batch of events. You get back another X-Showpad-Scroll-Id that you can use to fetch the third batch of events etc.
This way, you can do a loop in the application until they fetched all events they want. When no events return in the response, this indicates the end. There are millions of events in the database and it's not possible to return everything in one go, therefore you can scroll until you have all events

Comment: I just want to understand how to pass the response value to iterate the copy activity

Comment: the response having the headers as below                                                                 access-control-expose-headers: X-Showpad-Scroll-Id 
 x-showpad-scroll-id: 'its value '